# How to change iPhone deployment target

Tags: ios, iphone, flutter, dart, podfile

I have updated flutter today also with Xcode and I'm getting an error when trying to run my app on IOS

> warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target
> 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 7.0, but the range of supported
> deployment target versions is 8.0 to 13.4.99. (in target
> 'gRPC-C++-gRPCCertificates-Cpp' from project 'Pods')
>
> ...

When I go to a runner from Xcode I can only change it to min version 8

[image]

Flutter doctor result

> [✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.9-pre.2, on Mac OS X
> 10.15.4 19E266, locale en-GB)
> • Flutter version 1.12.13+hotfix.9-pre.2 at /Users/peter/development/tools/flutter
> • Framework revision f139b11009 (3 days ago), 2020-03-30 13:57:30 -0700
> • Engine revision af51afceb8
> • Dart version 2.7.2
>
> [✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK
> version 29.0.2)
> • Android SDK at /Users/peter/Library/Android/sdk
> • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
> • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.2
> • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
> • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b4-5784211)
> • All Android licenses accepted.
>
> [✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.4)
> • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
> • Xcode 11.4, Build version 11E146
> • CocoaPods version 1.8.4
>
> [✓] Android Studio (version 3.6)
> • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
> • Flutter plugin version 44.0.2
> • Dart plugin version 192.7761
> • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b4-5784211)
>
> [✓] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2019.3)
> • IntelliJ at /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app
> • Flutter plugin version 42.1.4
> • Dart plugin version 193.5731
>
> [✓] Connected device (1 available)
> • iPhone 11 Pro Max • 269B6B4A-E1E4-4461-B0F8-02DA3D21E477 • ios • com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-13-4 (simulator)

So how can I change the iPhone deployment target to a higher version in
flutter?

**UPDATE**

Updating the android studio gets rid of the error.

Comment: Does anybody got a solution for this

Comment: Just make sure you adroid studio is up to date

Answer (score 0):

You can change the deployment target by updating the `platform` configured on the Podfile to the intended version. The line to be updated is:

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
```

Then run `flutter pub cache repair` to refresh any configs set on the project.

Answer (score 0):

In flutter project

> IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 7.0

replace with

> IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 8.0

with "command + shift + R" > Replace All.
[image]